# Java inputstream to string in case of a sentence

Tags: java, string, inputstream

I have an external program (packaged in a jar) that I want to execute from another Java program, which I do using

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

This jar program now returns a sentence as output, which I want to use later on in the program, so I want to convert its output, for which I use the suggestion on using IOUtils I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string).

However

```
InputStream in = proc.getInputStream(); 
String myString = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
```

only return the first word of the sentence. Is it possible to get the full sentence out of the inputstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If feasible I would take the approach of calling the other JAR's main method immediately.
This is not isolated, but you may set the System.out to capture all text.

```
void startOtherApp(String[] args) {
    final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    PrintStream oldOut = System.out;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(baos, false, ENCODING)) {
        System.setOut(out);
        OtherJarsMain.main(args);
        out.flush();
        System.setOut(oldOut);
        String s = baos.toString(ENCODING);
        System.out.println("OUTPUT:\n" + s);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

To find the main class (here OtherJarsMain), open the jar with 7zip/WinZip or so, and look in /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. There there is a text line with `"Main-Class: aa.bb.OtherJarsMain"`.

Comment: It's a compiled jar, so I don't have access to the original java files in order to know what input the original main method takes.

Comment: I extended my answer with how `java -jar ...` finds out the main class.